# Summarise string data to percentages with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given the following data:

```py
x = "foo"
y = "bar"
z = "baz"
t1 = "fior"
t2 = "ropir"

d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(type=[t1] * 4 + [t2] * 4, response=[x, y, x, x, x, z, z, z],))
```

which looks as

```
    type response
0   fior      foo
1   fior      bar
2   fior      foo
3   fior      foo
4  ropir      foo
5  ropir      baz
6  ropir      baz
7  ropir      baz
```

how can it be summarised to

```py
d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        type=[t1] * 3 + [t2] * 3,
        response=[x, y, z] * 2,
        percentage=[0.75, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.75],
    )
)
```

which is as

```
    type response  percentage
0   fior      foo        0.75
1   fior      bar        0.25
2   fior      baz        0.00
3  ropir      foo        0.25
4  ropir      bar        0.00
5  ropir      baz        0.75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `groupby` and normalized [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then `rename` the Series, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with all the possible couples type-response created with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) from `unique` values in each column then finally `reset_index`.

```
d1.groupby('type')['response'].value_counts(normalize=True)\
  .rename('percentage')\
  .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d1['type'].unique(), d1['response'].unique()],
                                      names=['type','response']), 
           fill_value=0)\
  .reset_index()

    type response  percentage
0   fior      foo        0.75
1   fior      bar        0.25
2   fior      baz        0.00
3  ropir      foo        0.25
4  ropir      bar        0.00
5  ropir      baz        0.75
```